# message_post on change of state odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to post message on  openchatter on state change. i used the following good but nothing happened.

in .py file.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('state')
def log_prod(self,state):
    if state in ["i"]:
        msg="Dear User: your account has been update"
        return self.message_post(body=msg)

state = fields.Selection([('i','Internship'),('j','Joined')])
```

on xml

```
 <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="i,j"/>
```

Even no error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `@api.onchange('state')` instead of `@api.depends('state')`

```
@api.onchange('state')
def log_prod(self,state):
    if state in ["i"]:
       msg="Dear User: your account has been update"
       return self.message_post(body=msg)
```

Comment: Received Error: log_prod() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)

Comment: we access directly self.state

Comment: I add @api.multi with the code and again received log_prod() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: use @api.onchange('state')

Comment: I was given another answer for this question... Hope this help.

Comment: i used the same code you post and changed the depends to the onchange('state') but received log_prod() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given) then removed log_prod(self,state) changed to log_prod(self), state in ["i"] to self.state in ["i"]  and in the xml state field on_change="log_prod" but again nothing happen also no error

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.onchange('state')
def log_prod(self):
   if self.state in ["i"]:
      msg="Dear User: your account has been update"
      return self.message_post(body=msg)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for you answer.

Comment: IF you can give me your skype id so i can send you some screen shot maybe it will help you understand where i am making mistakes . add me Skype: omeed.cj

Answer (score 0):

Just add argument tracking=True, in the state field. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

To Enable chatter first you need to inherit your model from mail.mesage class Example:

```
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _name = "sale.order"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
```

This will enable chatter functionality on your Model, now next thing you need todo is:

```
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Sales Order" version="7.0">
        ...
        </form>
        <sheet>
        ...
        </sheet>
        <div class="oe_chatter">
            <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
            <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
        </div>
    </field>
</record>
```

this will add chatter in your form view and then your message_post will show up.

code :

```
 <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="i,j"/>
```

is for statusbar not for chatter.

Bests